# how to the min and the max date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i want to substruct to fields between the min and the max date heres my query:

```
SELECT Max(km) - MIN(km)
from positions
where deviceid = 2
  and cast(devicetime as date) between MIN('2017-03-23') and Max('2017-03-23'))
```

but it gives an error.
PS, devicetime in the database is a datetime type, i'm using mysql
the error is:invalide group function
[image]

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: mysql...............

Comment: `MIN('2017-03-23')`?  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Furthermore you have a second closing bracket at the end with no corresponding bracket.

Comment: What exactly do you need ? be specific..

Comment: what you want to achieve with MIN('2017-03-23') and Max('2017-03-23'))?

Comment: You cannot use `min` and `max` functions in `where` clause. Either form a subquery or follow `having` after `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `MIN` and `MAX` in between:

```
SELECT Max(km) - MIN(km)
from positions
where deviceid = 2
  and cast(devicetime as date) between '2017-03-23 00:00:00' and '2017-03-23 23:59:59'
```

Comment: suppose that the first line in the database inserted at 2017-03-23 00:02:00??

Comment: and the last one at 2017-03-23 23:57:59

Comment: @abdellatifzoumhane does no matter. the values in between are the possible  min and max range and not related to the values in the database

Comment: @abdellatifzoumhane yes i think so. but try it out and you will know it

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT Max(km) - MIN(km)
from positions
where deviceid = 2
and cast(devicetime as date) between '2017-03-23' and '2017-03-23'
```

You can't use aggregation functions in the where clause, only in select, having or order by clause.

Comment: but i need between tne min and the max date

Comment: `MIN('2017-03-23')` is `'2017-03-23'`... Also, I now noticed you have the same values in the between and in the and parts. This is the same as using `=`...

Answer (score 0):

Remove min & max from `where`....that is not allowed. Try the below sql. Added timestamp so you get the accurate result.

```
SELECT Max(km) - MIN(km)
from positions
where deviceid = 2
  and cast(devicetime as date) between '2017-03-23 00:00:00' and '2017-03-23 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use below code,

```
   SELECT Max(km) - MIN(km) KiloMeter FROM positions
   where deviceid = 2
   Group by deviceid,devicetime
   Having cast(devicetime as datetime) between MIN('2017-03-21') and Max('2017-03-26')
```

Please look in to aggregate and non-aggregate functions..

Thank you..

Comment: OP asks for mysql not SQL-server

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem are the aggregation functions in the `WHERE` clause.  However, you should also note that when using columns in the `WHERE`, it is a bad idea to use functions or type casting.  That prevents the use of indexes.

So, a better version uses inequalities:

```
select min(km) - max(km)
from positions
where deviceid = 2 and
      devicetime >= '2017-03-23' and
      devicetime < '2017-03-24';
```

If performance is an issue, you want an index on `positions(deviceid, devicetime, km)`.